# See who disabled a build in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

Is it possible to see the user who disabled a build in Jenkins? Either via the UI, the admin console or using a plugin?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes you can see it using [Job config history](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JobConfigHistory+Plugin) plugin

Comment: Is there a way to see who disabled a project if this plugin hasn't been installed yet?